# Confusion about the electrolyte in an electrochemical cell

Tags: electrochemistry

So the cathode is magnesium and the anode copper. The question asks why silver nitrate would not be a good electrolyte. I am confused. Also is the anode always inert in these cells?

Comment: Both magnesium and copper are spontaneously oxidized by silver ions, so this just deposits silver and produces heat. Also, if this was to be a galvanic cell, magnesium would be the anode and copper would be the cathode. See the Daniell cell for a similar situation, with Zn in place of Mg.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed said, that both copper and magnesium will reduce silver ions to elemental silver (you have to justify why in your answer. Hint: Look at the electrochemical series and compare the position of Mg, Cu, and Ag half cells. Another fundamental aspect is that one cannot apply Nernst equation if the metal dips in anything else besides its ions.

For instance, think little dip deeper, can we calculate the potential of copper electrode dipping NaCl solution (wrt to some reference cell?). In this case sodium ions will not react with copper or magnesium.